# speeding up a deletion in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I came up with:

```
drop table if exists idtemp;
create temp table idtemp as 
      select documentid from taskflag where taskid='coref' and state = 2 
         order by statechanged asc limit howmany;
create unique index on idtemp(documentid);

-- trim taskflag to the first N docs ordered by coref.
delete from taskflag where documentid not in (select documentid from idtemp) ;
```

This is very slow when there are 120k records in taskflag and I'm keeping 10k.

Taskflag looks like:

```
\d taskflag
                Table "public.taskflag"
    Column    |            Type             | Modifiers 
--------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 documentid   | character varying(64)       | not null
 taskid       | character varying(64)       | not null
 state        | smallint                    | 
 statechanged | timestamp without time zone | 
Indexes:
    "taskflag_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (documentid, taskid)
    "task_index2" btree (documentid)
    "task_index4" btree (taskid, state, statechanged)
```

Explain says:

```
                                QUERY PLAN                                    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Delete on taskflag  (cost=0.00..105811822.25 rows=223210 width=6)
   ->  Seq Scan on taskflag  (cost=0.00..105811822.25 rows=223210 width=6)
         Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..449.00 rows=10000 width=146)
                 ->  Seq Scan on idtemp  (cost=0.00..184.00 rows=10000 width=146)
(6 rows)
```

Should I just arrange for the temp table to contain the ones I am keeping?

Comment: Why do you create that intermediate table in the first place? Did you try to delete the rows from taskflag directly? (without the intermediate table).

Comment: I have four other tables to also trim, and I (ahem) assumed that it had to be worthwhile to factor out the selection of the ids to keep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest optimization would probably be to let the planner use a hash anti join, by rewriting the query as:

```
 delete from taskflag where not exists
  (select 1 from idtemp where documentid=taskflag.documentid);
```

also you may need to ANALYZE the temp table immediately after populating it.

Comment: I kept trying to remember how to write this as a join and could not think of not exists. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've set up a test.
Trying to delete the way you did gives pretty much the same query plan.
If you perform an `ANALYZE idtemp` before deleting, the plan changes to the following:

```
                                QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Delete on taskflag  (cost=198.00..3041.00 rows=60000 width=6)
   ->  Seq Scan on taskflag  (cost=198.00..3041.00 rows=60000 width=6)
         Filter: (NOT (hashed SubPlan 1))
         SubPlan 1
           ->  Seq Scan on idtemp  (cost=0.00..173.00 rows=10000 width=24)
```

And the way a_horse_with_no_name suggested:

```
EXPLAIN delete from taskflag where not (taskid='coref' and state = 2);

                             QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 Delete on taskflag  (cost=0.00..3509.13 rows=1 width=6)
   ->  Seq Scan on taskflag  (cost=0.00..3509.13 rows=1 width=6)
         Filter: (((taskid)::text <> 'coref'::text) OR (state <> 2))
```

On my test box, I had no patience to wait for your version to complete :)  The first version with `ANALYZE` completes a bit over 1 second (but it takes over an additional half second performing the `INSERT` and the `CREATE INDEX`, which means around 2 secs overall), the rephrased `DELETE` just a bit under 1 second.

@a_horse_with_no_name's second suggestion (see the comment below) with the following code

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS idtemp;

CREATE TABLE idtemp AS 
    SELECT documentid 
    FROM taskflag 
    WHERE taskid = 'coref' AND state = 2 
    ORDER BY statechanged ASC LIMIT 10000;

ALTER TABLE idtemp
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_taskflag PRIMARY KEY (documentid, taskid);

CREATE INDEX idx_11 ON idtemp (documentid);

CREATE INDEX idx_12 ON idtemp (taskid, state, statechanged);

ANALYZE idtemp;

DROP TABLE taskflag;

ALTER TABLE idtemp RENAME TO taskflag;
```

also takes some 900 ms, which means that in this particular case (with my particular test data) this approach is quite competitive.  If your `taskflag` table had dependent objects, it would not work though.

Comment: A third solution might be to create a new table with just the rows to keep (`CREATE TABLE .. AS SELECT ...`) then drop the old one and rename the new one.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - added this case as well, thanks for the suggestion.